# VSCode opening Chrome for links in the console, despite Safari being my default browser

Tags: visual-studio-code

I checked, and Safari is my default browser. However, I installed Chrome for web development tasks. I never allowed Chrome to be the default, and now when I try to send a new branch, Bitbucket gives me the link to create a new pull request. To my surprise, when I clicked with the command key pressed, VS Code opened Chrome.

I used Chrome before, so I didn't notice this difference, but now I don't want Chrome opening any links.

PS. I'm asking here because the VS Code repository redirects any questions to StackOverflow.