# Set non-windows-default browser as vscode-wide browser

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Edge as my personal browser and I want to set Chrome as a default browser for VSCode, without having to set it as Windows Default browser.

I've looked at a few solutions here and they do not work, such as:

- Putting up a Tasks.json file with some configuration
- setting custom browser on preferences (only works for live server)
- looking for webview configurations (do not exist anymore)

So I want to click a given link inside the terminal (such as localhost:5173) and open chrome instead of Edge. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: sounds kind of like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/77250098/11107541